# Edit text of button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, field

What I would like to do is have the text of a button that is editable upon clicking.

I understand how to change the value to one that is hard-coded but what I would like is...

- Click the button and a field will appear.
- This field would allow you to type in a new name for the button.
- After submitting the field, the text of the button would have changed to the field value.

The goal is a button that has a text value which is editable and other buttons which increment a number value associated with how many of the field there are.

```
| - | Item Name - 1 | + |
```

or

```
[subtraction button] | Name of Item - # of item | [addition button]
```

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: will you show us what have you done so far? At least your html!!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. See [what is a well-defined programming problem?](http://alexanderstopher.me/?p=15).

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/m1v0hyjk/1/)

What I have done is that I'll get the text entered in the input field and use it to set the Text of the Button in onClick event of the button.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="btn_text" />
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = document.getElementById("btn_text").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your code? You can post it, but if not, you can do the following:

**jQuery**

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").show();
});
$("input").blur(function() {
    $("button").text($(this).val());
    $(this).val("");
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**Or want you a pure js**

```
var bt = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
bt.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.style.display = "inline";
});
input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    bt.innerText = this.value;
    this.style.display = "none";
    this.value = "";
});
```

**html**

```
<button>Click me</button>
<input type="text" style="display:none">
```

**Demo using jQuery:** http://jsfiddle.net/x8714jgk/

**Demo using pure Js:** http://jsfiddle.net/x8714jgk/1/